# Node version problem with Yarn and typescript <error>

Tags: node.js, angular, yarnpkg

I had this error when I run Yarn on my angular project

```
@coreui/coreui-pro-angular-admin-template@2.4.3: The engine "node" is incompatible with this module. Expected version ">= ^8.9.4". Got "10.15.2"

node --version
```

is

```
v10.15.2

ng --version
```

is

```
    Angular CLI: 8.3.17
Node: 10.15.2
OS: win32 x64
Angular: <error>
... animations, cdk, cli, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core
... forms, http, language-service, platform-browser
... platform-browser-dynamic, router

Package                         Version
---------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect       0.803.17 (cli-only)
@angular-devkit/build-angular   <error>
@angular-devkit/core            8.3.17 (cli-only)
@angular-devkit/schematics      8.3.17 (cli-only)
@schematics/angular             8.3.17 (cli-only)
@schematics/update              0.803.17 (cli-only)
rxjs                            6.4.0 (cli-only)
typescript                      <error>
```

what does it mean and how could I fix this problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks All
I have found the problem
It was in `package.json`
I changed below

```
  "engines": {
"node": ">= ^8.9.4",
"npm": ">= 5.6.0"
  },
```

to be

```
  "engines": {
"node": ">= ^10.15.2",
"npm": ">= 5.6.0"
  },
```

Thanks for everybody

Answer (score 1):

You're package coreui-pro-angular-admin-template is probably outdated.

Try and update it with:

```
yarn upgrade coreui-pro-angular-admin-template@latest
```

By updating the package it will probably support node 10.

Comment: I have already  updated it but I had the same error

Comment: In you're question the package version is 2.4.3, the latest version is 2.9.3. Maybe you can try and update to that version.

Comment: Thank you it was in package.json